# Render DASH components via websocket

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-dash

Is it possible to render serialised Dash components on the front-end?

Here a small self-container application that links a button-click to a callback.
The callback internally emits five messages via a socket, and those messages are received from the front-end and the content of the message is logged to the console.

Instead of simply logging the content of the message to the console, I would like to make use of the `DashRenderer` in some way to render the serialised dash_html_components to proper HTML (and inserting them into the HTML DOM tree).

```
import dash_html_components as html
from dash import Dash
from flask import Flask
from dash.dependencies import Input
from dash.dependencies import Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

# add socketio script to javascript
external_scripts = [
    {
        'src': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js',
        'integrity': 'sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=',
        'crossorigin': 'anonymous'
    }
]

server = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(server)

app = Dash(__name__, server=server, external_scripts=external_scripts, serve_locally=True)

app.index_string = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {%metas%}
        <title>{%title%}</title>
        {%favicon%}
        {%css%}
    </head>
    <body>
        {%app_entry%}
        <footer>
            {%config%}
            {%scripts%}
            <script>
                var socket = io();
                socket.on("component-channel", function (component, cb) {
                   console.log("Component: ")
                   console.log(component)
                });
            </script>
            {%renderer%}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
'''

app.layout = html.Div(
    id="outer-div", children=[
        html.Button("Send event", id="button"),
        html.Div(id="output-div")
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("output-div", "children"),
    [Input("button", "n_clicks")]
)
def on_click(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate()

    import time
    for i in range(5):
        component = html.P("Loop {}".format(i))
        serialised_component = component.to_plotly_json()
        socketio.emit("component-channel", serialised_component)
        time.sleep(2)

    return html.P("Terminated")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run_server()
```

How do I render the data received in the websocket into proper HTML?

Below a gif showing the current behaviour of the application, i.e. the data sent via the websocket from the server to the front-end is received and logged via the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)
I think you should use

`React.createElement( type, [props], [...children] )`